# Why does .NET XMLSerializer automatically change my namespace prefixes (alias)?

Tags: vb.net, web-services, web, namespaces

I am working on a web service that needs to return faults in a way that is defined by the standards of our type of business. This requires me to return a fault as this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
  <wsse:Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <Timestamp xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" />
  </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>s:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Operator/operand type mismatch.</faultstring>
      <faultactor>urn:dealernumberID:??????</faultactor>
      <detail>
        <ErrorType xmlns="http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2009/transport">Backend Client Fault</ErrorType>
        <ErrorDetail xmlns="http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2009/transport">Backend client returned a fault</ErrorDetail>
      </detail>
   </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I create the fault like this, but when the service sends it, it looks like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:h="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <Timestamp xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" />
    </h:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <s:Fault>
      <faultcode>s:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Operator/operand type mismatch.</faultstring>
      <faultactor>urn:dealernumberID:??????</faultactor>
      <detail>
        <ErrorType xmlns="http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2009/transport">Backend Client Fault</ErrorType>
        <ErrorDetail xmlns="http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2009/transport">Backend client returned a fault</ErrorDetail>
      </detail>
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Why does this happen? Is there a setting that I can change in .NET to keep it from doing this by default? I do understand that a namespace is a namespace regardless of the prefix, but like I said, the standard dictates we do it a certain way (most likely to accommodate third parties that are reading responses as strings?)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: An [mcve] would be useful, or at least the relevant code.

Comment: Have you tried passing the Namespaces along in your Serialize method as documented here?! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163161(v=vs.110).aspx